# How to fix 'Error in processing request Error text: error (rejected)' No Error Code in phpmyadmin while click button Update

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin

I have server with apache, php, mysql, and phpmyadmin installed. I access phpmyadmin in another computer using intranet, when i click button 'update' (just this button) in phpmyadmin appear error Error in processing request Error text: error (rejected). No code in that error.

But, when i tried direct in localhost (on server), no problem.

On check console chrome: error jquery.min.js?v=4.9.0.1:2 POST http://x.x.x.x:8080/phpmyadmin/lint.php net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Somebody can help? What's wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Try this https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/91893-allowing-remote-access-to-phpmyadmin

Comment: @rawdog not work, still error. :) Thanks anyway.